# Use Ontology to correctly assign data types in Virtuoso

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology, semantic-web, virtuoso

I have ingested the Geonames RDF dump (https://download.geonames.org/all-geonames-rdf.zip) into a Virtuoso instance, and I've been running queries against it with varying degrees of success. However, I've found that certain objects have the incorrect datatype. For example, population is encoded using xsd:string, and therefore trying to sort by population ends up sorting the results in lexicographic order:

```
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX  gn:   <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#>

SELECT ?country ?name ?population (datatype(?population) AS ?type)
WHERE {
    ?country a gn:Feature .
    ?country gn:name ?name .

    # A.PCLI is feature  code for 'independent political entity'
    ?country gn:featureCode <https://www.geonames.org/ontology#A.PCLI> .
    ?country gn:population ?population .
}
ORDER BY DESC(?population)
LIMIT 10
```

| country | name | population | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| https://sws.geonames.org/1814991/ | China | 1330044000 | http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string |
| https://sws.geonames.org/1269750/ | India | 1173108018 | http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string |
| https://sws.geonames.org/6252001/ | United States | 310232863 | http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string |
| https://sws.geonames.org/1643084/ | Indonesia | 242968342 | http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string |
| https://sws.geonames.org/3469034/ | Brazil | 201103330 | http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string |

I know I can cast the variable to get the correct result like so `ORDER BY DESC(xsd:integer(?population))`, but once my queries get more complicated, this no longer works. Specifically, when running sub queries and using the results to apply further logic. For example:

```
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX  gn:   <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#>

SELECT ?cityName ?countryName ?population datatype(?population)
WHERE
{
    ?city  gn:parentCountry ?country ;
           gn:population    ?population ;
           gn:name          ?cityName .

    ?country gn:name ?countryName .

    {
        # a) SELECT ?country (MAX(?population) AS ?population)
        # b) SELECT ?country (MAX(xsd:integer(?population)) AS ?population)     
        # c) SELECT ?country (xsd:string(MAX(xsd:integer(?population))) AS ?population)
        WHERE 
        {
            ?city   a                gn:Feature ;
                    gn:featureClass  <https://www.geonames.org/ontology#P> ;
                    gn:population    ?population ;
                    gn:parentCountry ?country .

        }
        GROUP BY ?country
        ORDER BY DESC(?population)
    }
}
```

Select `a` returns the populations in lexicographic order, as before.
Select `b` correctly orders the populations, but seeing as the result set has cast the population to integers, I can no longer match the city using population outside the sub query as I'm comparing strings with integers. So `b` returns an empty result set.
Select `c` was my attempt at recasting the results back to strings in order to be able to match them outside the sub query, but this ends in a timeout (estimated 4000 second execution time).

My question is this: Is there a way to either

a) change the datatype in Virtuoso manually 
b) use the Geonames ontology to instruct Virtuoso about the correct types 
c) alter my query to more efficiently cast to the correct type

I'm hoping option b is possible, as this seems the most effective solution, because the Geonames ontology correctly specifies the types to all of the resulting predicate's objects.

You can find the Geoname ontology [here](https://www.geonames.org/ontology/ontology_v3.2.rdf). 
You can test the queries above and your own against our endpoint here:
http://18.170.45.162:8890/sparql

Comment: There is no magical autocast, the data index is created during loading of the data - so you have to modify the data before or after. With after I mean, you could simply use a SPARQL `INSERT {} DELETE {} WHERE {}` on all `gn:population` triples. So you' ll update your data which in fact updates the DB index. you could even make this generic for all data properties in the ontology. the constructor `strdt` allows the pass a datatype URI which you can take from the `rdfs:range` declared in the ontology

Comment: Thanks @UninformedUser. Can you specify what you mean by strdt? How would I use sparql to change the datatype? In your example, do you mean I should INSERT the new population triple, while deleting the old one?

Comment: yep, you basically replace it. Like `INSERT {?s gn:population    ?newPop } DELETE {?s gn:population    ?pop } WHERE {?s gn:population    ?pop BIND(strdt(str(?pop), xsd:integer) AS ?newPop)}`

Comment: @UninformedUser amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another option, based on your query (a) --

Put your CAST into the SELECT, as --

```
SELECT                              ?cityName 
                                    ?countryName 
                                    ?population
       (xsd:integer(?population) AS ?pop) 
          (datatype(?population) AS ?PopDataType)
```

and then `ORDER BY DESC (4)` (for the 4th variable in your select). This retains the data as inserted, which may be valuable in some scenarios.

Here's the [full query](http://18.170.45.162:8890/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX%20%20xsd%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20gn%3A%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.geonames.org%2Fontology%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FcityName%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FcountryName%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fpopulation%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28xsd%3Ainteger%28%3Fpopulation%29%20AS%20%3Fpop%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28datatype%28%3Fpopulation%29%20AS%20%3FPopDataType%29%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20%20gn%3AparentCountry%20%3Fcountry%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gn%3Apopulation%20%20%20%20%3Fpopulation%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gn%3Aname%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FcityName%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20gn%3Aname%20%3FcountryName%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20a%29%20%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%28MAX%28%3Fpopulation%29%20AS%20%3Fpopulation%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20b%29%20SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%28MAX%28xsd%3Ainteger%28%3Fpopulation%29%29%20AS%20%3Fpopulation%29%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20c%29%20SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%28xsd%3Astring%28MAX%28xsd%3Ainteger%28%3Fpopulation%29%29%29%20AS%20%3Fpopulation%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20%20%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gn%3AFeature%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gn%3AfeatureClass%20%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.geonames.org%2Fontology%23P%3E%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gn%3Apopulation%20%20%20%20%3Fpopulation%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gn%3AparentCountry%20%3Fcountry%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fcountry%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ORDER%20BY%20DESC%20%284%29&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on) --

```
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX  gn:   <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#>

SELECT                              ?cityName 
                                    ?countryName 
                                    ?population
       (xsd:integer(?population) AS ?pop) 
          (datatype(?population) AS ?PopDataType)
WHERE
{
    ?city  gn:parentCountry ?country ;
           gn:population    ?population ;
           gn:name          ?cityName .

    ?country gn:name ?countryName .
    {
        # a) 
SELECT ?country (MAX(?population) AS ?population)
        # b) SELECT ?country (MAX(xsd:integer(?population)) AS ?population)     
        # c) SELECT ?country (xsd:string(MAX(xsd:integer(?population))) AS ?population)
        WHERE 
        {
            ?city   a                gn:Feature ;
                    gn:featureClass  <https://www.geonames.org/ontology#P> ;
                    gn:population    ?population ;
                    gn:parentCountry ?country .
        }
        GROUP BY ?country
    }
}
        ORDER BY DESC (4)
```

-- and [results](http://18.170.45.162:8890/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX%20%20xsd%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20gn%3A%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.geonames.org%2Fontology%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FcityName%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FcountryName%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fpopulation%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28xsd%3Ainteger%28%3Fpopulation%29%20AS%20%3Fpop%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28datatype%28%3Fpopulation%29%20AS%20%3FPopDataType%29%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20%20gn%3AparentCountry%20%3Fcountry%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gn%3Apopulation%20%20%20%20%3Fpopulation%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gn%3Aname%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FcityName%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20gn%3Aname%20%3FcountryName%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20a%29%20%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%28MAX%28%3Fpopulation%29%20AS%20%3Fpopulation%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20b%29%20SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%28MAX%28xsd%3Ainteger%28%3Fpopulation%29%29%20AS%20%3Fpopulation%29%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20c%29%20SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%28xsd%3Astring%28MAX%28xsd%3Ainteger%28%3Fpopulation%29%29%29%20AS%20%3Fpopulation%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20%20%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gn%3AFeature%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gn%3AfeatureClass%20%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.geonames.org%2Fontology%23P%3E%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gn%3Apopulation%20%20%20%20%3Fpopulation%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gn%3AparentCountry%20%3Fcountry%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fcountry%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ORDER%20BY%20DESC%20%284%29&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on).

You might also consider upgrading your Virtuoso from Release 6.1 (06.01.3127) which hasn't been updated since roughly Feb, 2010 (though your binary was apparently compiled in 2019) to a [current build of Release 7](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/releases) from the much more recent codebase.  This is vital if you intend to perform GeoSPARQL queries, as this support was not added until Release 7.1, circa 2018!

UPDATED TO ADD:

To get full GeoSPARQL functionality from Virtuoso, it's necessary to follow the ["Virtuoso GeoSPARQL support" guidance](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/blob/develop/7/README.GeoSPARQL.md) on the Open Source GitHub Project and/or the [Virtuoso Geospatial Enhancements](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtGeoSPARQLEnhancementDocs) section of the Virtuoso Product Manual.  The ["Virtuoso GeoSPARQL Demo Server"](https://community.openlinksw.com/t/virtuoso-geosparql-demo-server/223) article in the Community Forum can also be helpful, as can testing on the [GeoSPARQL Demo instance](https://geosparql.demo.openlinksw.com/sparql).

Comment: Thanks a million @TallTed, really appreciate your answer. We've updated our version to Release 7.1 as you have suggested. 

A quick question: is there no way at all to use the ontology file where the population's datatype is already encoded, e.g.

`<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#population">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Feature"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">population</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>`

when loading the xml data to correctly identify datatypes?

Comment: @Doogyb — First, my suggestion was update *to the latest available*, not just to 7.1. GeoSPARQL was first added in 7.1, with a number of refinements, fixes, and enhancements made since then. As none of this is really a programming quesiton, but rather a product-specific usage concern, it would be better to raise it on our [Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com/) or as an [issue against the Open Source project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/).

Comment: @Doogyb — I added some links, to additional Virtuoso GeoSPARQL information, as well as our GeoSPARQL demo instance, which may help you get further.